# Extracting point data from raster files

Tags: raster, r, extract

I have many raster data in tiff format. I need to extract the values for some coordinates and save it as a csv file.
I have a code to extract data from some stations across the raster flies, and the code works as long as I extract just one station. Once, I put other coordinates to extract their values it gives errors. so I have to run the code for each of stations separately (I have 8 stations).

Can you help me modify the code?

```
library(raster)
library(sp) # used to create a SpatialPoint object
setwd("c:/PET")


# LOAD RASTERS INTO A LIST OBJECT. 
tmp <- lapply(list.files("c:/PET", pattern = ".tif$", full.names = TRUE), raster)


coords <- data.frame(

# **1st station**
"lat" = c(498957.72),"lon" = c(4516020.57)


)

pts <- SpatialPoints(coords = coords, 
              proj4string = CRS("+proj=utm +zone=16  +datum=WGS84 +units=m"))


outt=as.data.frame(cbind(coords, do.call("rbind", lapply(tmp, extract, pts))))

write.csv(outt, file="myFileName.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 4):

I think your penultimate line of code needs modification. Right now, the #  objects in your list determines the # rows in your output data.frame. You are then receiving an error because the station coordinates most likely have a different # rows.

In order to fix this, replace your `rbind()` call inside `do.call()` with a `cbind()`, and add the coordinates afterwards. Like that, you make sure that the extracted value matrix and station coordinates have identical # rows. Optionally, you may then transform the output data.frame from wide (ie. high # columns) into long format (ie. high # rows).

```
library(remote)
library(reshape2)

## example raster data
data(vdendool)
tmp = unstack(vdendool)

## create random points
set.seed(123)
pts = as(sampleRandom(vdendool, size = 5, sp = TRUE), "SpatialPoints")

coords = coordinates(pts)


### option #1: extract using *apply loop ----
xtr = do.call("cbind", lapply(tmp, extract, pts))
colnames(xtr) = names(vdendool)

out = data.frame(coords, xtr)

## if required, transform 'data.frame' from wide into long format
out = melt(out, id.vars = 1:2, variable.name = "layer")

head(out, 10)
#   x    y   layer      value
# 1  -175 67.5 layer.1 -24.620316
# 2  -165 32.5 layer.1  50.426976
# 3    85 62.5 layer.1 -34.658461
# 4   -45 27.5 layer.1 -17.551138
# 5  -125 22.5 layer.1 -12.083841
# 6  -175 67.5 layer.2  40.380589
# 7  -165 32.5 layer.2  25.252061
# 8    85 62.5 layer.2   4.944444
# 9   -45 27.5 layer.2   2.678345
# 10 -125 22.5 layer.2  -9.226877
```

Please note that in case your Raster* objects have the same properties (CRS, extent, resolution), you may as well `stack()` the single layers currently stored in the list and run `extract()` directly on the resulting RasterStack, thus avoiding the need for a loop structure altogether.

```
### option #2: use stacked Raster* objects -----

rst = stack(tmp)
xtr = extract(rst, pts)
out = data.frame(coords, xtr)

## same here, use reshape2::melt to bring 'data.frame' into long format
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am just not sure how to add my coordinates to your code? what does pts does in your script as I think it's different with mine

Comment: Since you didn't provide a reproducible example, I had to select points myself; that's what `sampleRandom()` is doing. I converted 'pts' to SpatialPoints, which is similar to what you are dealing with when calling `SpatiaPoints()` on your 'coords' variable. The rest remains the same.